# Why are request params like `1duh` treated like `1` in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, parameters

This might be an academic/philosophical question, but suppose I have a resource, in Rails, and I GET `localhost:3000/resources/2foobar`, this gets served as if `foobar` was not there. While this is cool at first, it begs the question if something may be missing behind the scenes. I generally trust open source projects, and Rails had been around long enough for me to be confident, but wouldn't it be better if we could validate the parameter to check if it's strictly numeric and not just starting with a number? For example, I could modify my `show` method like

```
if (Integer(params[:id]) != nil rescue false)
  render json: @resource
else
  head: 400
end
```

Can someone explain the rationale for treating `1duh` as `1`, in Rails?

**EDIT** Example request

```
$ curl 'localhost:3000/resources/1ds'
```

Corresponding log

```
Started GET "/resources/1ds" for ::1 at 2016-06-26 20:35:59 +0100
Processing by ResourcesController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1ds"}
  Resource Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `resources`.* FROM `resources` WHERE `resources`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

curl returns

```
{"id":"1","data":"foobarsampledata"}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to treat your meaning of "treated". Can you elaborate on that? "gets served" where? Any logs to support? As far as I can see rails can pass in params id `2foobar` and your controller can get it, so where is that "treating" is happening? Also, did you actually meant `localhost:3000/resource/2foobar` or `localhost:3000/resourceS/2foobar`?

Comment: I added a little sample in the questions. As you can see, I GET `/resources/1ds`, `1ds` is taken in like that and passed to `Resource::find` which in turn considers it to be `1` alone (see SQL query) and returns the resource with id 1. I tried again requesting `/resources/ds1` and I got a 404 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) is your answer:

> If the primary key is an integer, find by id coerces its arguments using to_i.

```
Person.find("1")        # returns the object for ID = 1
Person.find("31-sarah") # returns the object for ID = 31
```

So, the rationale is your primary key. And I guess, if your primary key would not be an integer, this (conversion to_i) would not be happening.

Comment: I see. So, I essentially can trust .to_i to do its job correctly behind the scenes — i.e., there's very little chance of a SQL injection through .find…

Comment: You can trust to_i and find. In fact, you can go "paranoid" and add constrains on the integer in your routes file too, but I think it is an overkill. To avoid SQL injections just make sure you do not insert your params **directly** into query condition strings and such, and you should be OK.